# HTML webpage full screen

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I have this webpage and you can see that I have white space around the webpage. I tried to configure the CSS to width and height to 100% but not sure why its not reach the whole screen:

http://luc.edu/loyolamaps/basemap/

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Ok this helped and I got it to appear the whole width and height for my wrapper but now the map has a big white gap at the bottom above the footer: luc.edu/loyolamaps/basemap Does anyone know how to fix that? I tried various CSS edits but nothing is making the map the whole height to the footer.

Comment: I don't see the gap. What browser are you in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

That will allow the contents to reach the outter-limits of the viewport.

Comment: Only if those other elements are set to inherit the padding or margins from their parent, which is not the default.

Comment: @animuson: My first example used `*, body` but I've since revised it, so you'd be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

The body element has a `margin: 10px` on it by default, just add a `margin: 0` to your body's CSS and it should be fine.

Comment: Ok this helped and I got it to appear the whole width and height for my wrapper but now the map has a big white gap at the bottom above the footer:

http://luc.edu/loyolamaps/basemap/

Does anyone know how to fix that? I tried various CSS edits but nothing is making the map the whole height to the footer.